# Angular2 cli - how to load external data during bootstrap before canActivate triggers?

Tags: angular, store

I have some http calls that need to processed in the app component before the canActivate guard method triggers.

The routing looks like this at the moment:

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AccessGuard] },
```

So I want canActivate method of AccessGuard to run after the App component constructor is completed calling all the http calls.

But right now before the http calls in the AppComponent are completed, the canActivate triggers and hence find no data in store.

Comment: What if you add a child to your `home` path ? Then home makes the HTTP calls, and you can show the `router-outlet` based on the results

Comment: @trichetriche: Can you give me an example of what you mean? I don't have any child component in home so how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment, but right now I need to use an answer.

So, if you use a child for your route component :

```
{ path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, canActivateChild: [AccessGuard], children: [
    // Paths to your children
] },
```

This way, home can make the HTTP calls, while children are protected by the guard. It's what you want, right ?

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

Try this :

```
{ path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AccessGuard] }
```

As your only route, and :

```
this.yourHttpService.yourCall().subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
})
```

In your app component (don't forget to import `Router` from `@angular/router`)

Comment: The HTTP calls are made in the AppComponent and not in the HomeComponent. When I access url http://localhost:4200/ in the browser, I am redirected to the home page as per the routing shown above which has canActivate. The issue is that AppComponent Http calls are not yet completed and the canActivate method is completed first. How can I make sure that AppComponent is fully completed before the canActivate is triggered

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit. Your app doesn't go through appComponent, because you make a direct redirect. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I do want to redirect it but want Http calls to complete first before canActive is called. If I move the http calls to gaurd itself then it means everytime canActivate is called (for all routes) I have to make http calls. Rather, I want to make http calls in the app components and store the data in redux store then any component (including canActivate ) can directly query store rather than going to the server (http call). I hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your edit, please see my updated answer and tell me if you get it

Comment: The problem is even If I try to access the url in the browser http://localhost:4200/home I still get canActivate completed first before AppComponent's Http calls are completed. I think its to do with asyn calls i.e. http calls are taking longer and in between canActivate completes first ...

Comment: With the solution I gave you, there's absolutely no way that appComponent isn't called. Maybe you should try it ?

Comment: The AppComponent is called but the http calls inside the AppComponent are not completed and canActivate triggers and completes first is the problem. I have multiple Http calls in AppComponent I can't route to /home in one and leave others blank.

Comment: If you're still redirected, then you have left your `redirectTo` path. Delete it and try again.